# Как оставить закреплённым поле поиска тега button, при вводе текста, после псевдокласса :focus?

Tags: html, css

Хочется закрепить открывающееся поле не только при наведении, но и при вводе текста.
Возможно сделать без использования скрипта?

```
<https://codepen.io/agma/pen/MWwGoGG>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если добавить `.searchIn:focus` к существующему `.searchBox:hover > .searchIn` то пока фокус на инпуте, то не закроется Ваш поиск

```
.searchBox:hover > .searchIn,
.searchIn:focus
{
  width: 240px;
  padding: 0 6px;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение!